# Error on using JavaMail to receive emails in Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get my emails using JavaMail in my Android application using this code:

```
private String[] ReadMailbox(String MailboxName) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    List<String> FromAddressArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myusername", "mypassword");
        ActiveMailbox = store.getFolder(MailboxName);
        ActiveMailbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = ActiveMailbox.getMessages();
        //System.out.println("Number of mails = " + messages.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            Address[] from = message.getFrom();
            FromAddressArrList.add(from[0].toString());
        }
        //ActiveMailbox.close(true);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] FromAddressArr = new String[FromAddressArrList.size()];
    FromAddressArrList.toArray(FromAddressArr);
    return FromAddressArr;
}
```

BUT I am getting this error when I run application:

`10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): java.lang.VerifyError: com/mailcry/android/MainActivity
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-19 16:48:00.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

I do not have experience in debugging Android or Java applications and I need your help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not add JavaMail to my libs Android application folder. Once I did, everything worked just fine.